# Tax software to file Form 1120s on Mac

Tags: osx

Does there exist business tax software to download or use online that supports Mac to file form 1120s? I'm an LLC with S-Corp tax status.

I'm aware of these two software programs but they are only for Windows.

[https://www.amazon.com/TurboTax-Business-Software-Federal-Exclusive/dp/B0BH5MHVH3/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BH5MHVH3) [https://www.amazon.com/Block-Software-Business-Exclusive-Download/dp/B0BCC4KXLK/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BCC4KXLK)

I'm aware I could run these on Mac with bootcamp, but I'd really prefer to find a solution on Mac to file my business taxes.